# Does hive 0.14 supports Theta Join. I could not find Documentation

Tags: hive

Is there support for Hive Theta join enabled in latest hive 0.14, we would like to perform Range Join using Theta Joins. In Hive 0.13 it is not available, As anyone have work around for theta joins?

We have range of IP values, we would like apply join to check IP is within range..

It would be nice if any one can share with me link related to hive data ware house analytics document to get more understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Try this:

```
select key, column1, column2 from table1 a
cross join
select key, column1, column2 from table2 b
where a.key > b.key;
```

Runs same as

```
select key, column1, column2 from table1 a
left outer join
select key, column1, column2 from table2 b
on (1=1)
where a.key > b.key;
```

Comment: thanks invoke....I have question on key, is key is index of hive table or row sequence